# A call to PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists() throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException in docker

Tags: .net-core

For some reason, on runtime, i would get exceptions for

```
 System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Performance Counters are not supported on this platform.) ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Performance Counters are not supported on this platform.
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(String categoryName)
```

But looking at the system diagnostics performancecounter document, the library is there for .NETCore 2.2

The document can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancecountercategory.exists?view=netcore-2.2

Comment: Which OS are you running in that docker container? Performance counters are only supported on Windows.

Comment: Got it. It makes sense. I was running it in a docker environment and it is running linux. I guess they should make their documentations clear. If you can answer the question i'll accept it as correct answer. Thanks